# Jquery accordion button toggle

Tags: jquery, button, html-table, row, accordion

I have a table, and in the table there are hidden rows (with a div inside) that expand when the user clicks on 'edit user'. I have got it to display only one of these rows at once, however I need the button to update from saying 'edit user' to 'close', but only for the row that is open. So when a user clicks on another 'edit user' button, the one that was open closes, and the button text (and span icon) changes back to what it was originally, and the row that is open updates to 'close', etc. Hope I've made this clear.

I have tried using toggle but I can't seem to figure it out. I am very new to Jquery and this seems a bit too advanced for my skills at the moment!

Here's my Jquery so far:

```
$(function() {
$.fn.slideFadeToggle  = function(speed, easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
};
    $('tr:nth-child(4n)').addClass("zebra")
    .prev().addClass("zebra")
    .prev().addClass("normal")
    .prev().addClass("normal");
    $('.hidden-user').hide()

$('td .button-small').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var toggledelement = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.hidden-user');             
    $(toggledelement).slideFadeToggle('slow');
    $('.hidden-user').not(toggledelement).slideUp('slow');

});

});
```

There's a link to jsfiddle here, I've included most of the css and html that I'm using in the project.

http://jsfiddle.net/hssay/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td .button-small').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var isActive = $(this).hasClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        if (!isActive) {
             $(this).find('.label').text('Close');   
        }    else {
             $(this).find('.label').text('Edit User');   
        }
        var toggledelement = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.hidden-user');             
        $(toggledelement).slideFadeToggle('slow');
        $('.hidden-user').not(toggledelement).slideUp('slow');

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hssay/1/
By toggling an active class, you can know if the next div is open or not.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is great, given me more insight into what I need to do - however, how do I dynamically add the active class and what am I adding it to? I've tried using ":visible" but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Further to my previous comment: I see that this is adding the active class to the button that's clicked, however it doesn't change the label text back to 'edit user' when another row is opened.

Comment: Well I did it pretty fast and hoped you could figure out by yourself how to do it ;) But heres it is. you just have to find the other active buttons and replace there text.  So right before "var isActive = ..." add this: $('.button-small.active').text('Edit User').removeClass('active'); This should work

Comment: Almost there, I've updated my jsfiddle, however I'm having trouble removing the active class when another button is clicked. If you click from the top down, everything seems to work just fine, however when you click a button for the second time, the active class gets confused, and it starts saying 'edit user' when the toggled element is open, and 'close' when the toggled element is closed. Brain melting! http://jsfiddle.net/YEkm9/